# Half-integral linear programs

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming

What are some of the known properties of half-integral linear programs?
That is, linear programs for which the solution vector always takes its values in the set $\{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}^n$.

I'm asking this in relation to half-integral linear programs that are relaxations of integer programs (are they "faster" in terms of complexity class, to solve?).

Comment: Sanity check... can one not simply multiply everything by 2 to get an integer program that is effectively the same problem?  It may be easier to find documentation on such problems since it's simply an integer problem with constraints.

Comment: @CortAmmon These are linear programs in which all extreme solutions (aka basic feasible solutions or vertices) are half-integral. For example, the vertex cover LP.